# Stop Powershell from exiting

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I know that there is that little `-noexit` switch for PowerShell.

Is there anyway of staying in the shell without using that switch?

In other words, I want a script command(s) that executes then leaves the shell open.

Comment: To be (even) more specific: User right-clicks on the skript, chooses "Run in Powershell" from context-menu, skript executes and leaves shell open.

Comment: you need to change context-menu luncher adding -noexit

Comment: Cristian, that's obviously NOT from within the skript.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This script will not exit if you run it without arguments, e.g. by double-clicking on it:

```
param($Work)

# restart PowerShell with -noexit, the same script, and 1
if (!$Work) {
    powershell -noexit -file $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path 1
    return
}

# now the script does something
# this script just outputs this:
'I am not exiting'
```

Comment: I though about posting this hack. Same technique as the UAC elevation hack. Not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 40):

You basically have 3 options to prevent the PowerShell Console window from closing, that I describe [in more detail on my blog post](http://blog.danskingdom.com/keep-powershell-console-window-open-after-script-finishes-running/).

1. **One-time Fix:** Run your script from the PowerShell Console, or launch the PowerShell process using the -NoExit switch. e.g. `PowerShell -NoExit "C:\SomeFolder\SomeScript.ps1"`
2. **Per-script Fix:** Add a prompt for input to the end of your script file. e.g. `Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"`
3. **Global Fix:** Change your registry key to always leave the PowerShell Console window open after the script finishes running.

See my blog for more information on which registry keys to modify.

Sounds like you are looking for option #1 or #3.

Answer (score 15):

Have you tried

```
$host.enternestedprompt()
```

That will stop execution and drop them to a nested prompt.  When they exit that prompt, then the script will finish and the window will close.

Comment: I just noticed the question is also tagged powershell-remoting. If the script in question is running as a job on a remote system, that hack will not work.

Answer (score 12):

```
"do stuff"
Pause
```

Yes, just like commandline -- output:

```
do stuff
Press Enter to continue...:
```

Comment: And how should the user use the powershell-window afterwards for entering commands?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a command you could run in the script that would prevent the shell from exiting if it had not been invoked using the `-noexit` command.

I typically use `Read-Host "Press ENTER to continue"` at the end if I don't want the shell to close. However this won't prevent the shell from closing after you press enter if it had not been started with `-noexit`.

Comment: So, thats unfortunately NOT what i need.

Comment: `noexit` changes the way PowerShell.exe initializes much like `cmd.exe /k`. Once it has been initialized one way I don't think it can be changed.

Answer (score 3):

The while loop at the end of this trivial script prompts me for a command and executes it. It runs with the environment of the script, so it is possible to check the values of variables. Entering "exit" terminates the loop when it is executed.

```
# Do something.

cd D:\temp
$current_directory = $(pwd)
dir

write-host  # Just add a little space after the dir

# Stay in the shell and execute commands.

while ($TRUE) {
  $cmd = Read-Host "PS $(pwd)"
  if ($cmd[0] -eq '"') { iex "& $cmd" } 
    else { iex $cmd }
}
```

I'm sure that others will be able to share some refinements, but this is a start. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
PowerShell -File  c:\myscript.ps1 -NoExit
```

Comment: No, that still would exit PS if i click the file containing your line. I need a way from WITHIN a skript to stop the CURRENT session from exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use `$null = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`.

Combining with other answers there are a few options:

- 1. From command prompt run: `PowerShell -NoExit "Path\to\Script\script.ps1"`
- 2. Add to end of script: `pause`
- 3. Add to end of script: `read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"`
- 4. Add to end of script: `$host.enternestedprompt()`
- 5. Add to end of script: `$null = host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`

Answer (score 0):

```
Powershell -noexit -command {
$a=1
Echo $a
} # End block
# Script ends but PowerShell windows remains.
```

Comment: this is exactly what the OP said was NOT wanted. [*grin*]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this isn't exactly what the OP wanted. He knows about -noexit but does he know he can use it like this to literally have "a script command(s) that executes then leaves the shell open" All he needs to do is append this to any script unless he really can't use it this specific way for some reason.

Answer (score -7):

Not to revive a 6-year-old thread or anything, but it should be noted to anyone reading that you can end your script with

```
Stop-Process -processname regedit
```

if you have the registry tweak (global fix) enabled and actually want to run an automatically-closing script.