# Start PowerShell process as administrator - Window closes

Tags: powershell

Using the below code in a PowerShell window:

```
$User = 'testuser1'
$Password = 'Pa$$w0rd' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object PSCredential -ArgumentList $User, $Password
Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential
```

This works fine, but the PowerShell instance is not in elevated administrator mode. I tried:

```
$Arguments = "Start-Process powershell -Verb -RunAs"
Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

This opens a PowerShell instance, but it closes immediately.

How can I stop the new, elevated PowerShell instance closing?

Comment: [`-noexit`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9362722/1701026)

Comment: You won't be able to bypass the UAC prompt, if that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Arguments = "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs"
Start-Process powershell -Credential $Credential -ArgumentList $Arguments
```

RunAs is not a parameter but value :)

If you correct this, you will be able to run Powershell console properly.